# variable importance -frequency and variable importance -cover (h2o)

Tags: h2o

For some models h2o can produce three forms of variable importance Analysis ( variable importance , variable importance -frequency and variable importance -cover) , can anyone point me to a reference explaining the differences ?

Comment: where are you seeing that H2O-3 can provide more than one form of variable importance? and which type of models are you trying to get variable importance from.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?:  http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/variable-importance.html.  Also possible duplidate:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12318/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-xgboost-importance